# Problem updating a list with redux toolkit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

```
// './file_1'

import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

export const array = createSlice({
    name: 'array',
    initialState: {
      value: []
    },
    reducers:{
      append(state, a) {
        state.value.push(a)
      }
    }
});

export const { append } = array.actions;
export default array.reducer;
```

I've also updated the store, so no problem on that side

```
'/.file_2'
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { append } from './file_1';
const dispatch = useDispatch()
let x = 5
dispatch(append(x));
```

raises this error:
Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {type, payload}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: show the code where the error is pointing to ... somewhere in returning JSX or returning value from component function

Comment: You mean the stack under the error? I'm a noob.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"a" is an object. The object looks like this -> {action: ..., payload: ...}
so you need to access it like this -> a.payload

Answer (score 0):

## Issue

The issue is that the code is attempting to render an object which isn't valid JSX.

Since you've no errors regarding arrays I'll assume you are correctly mapping it, something like this:

```
const array = useSelector(state => state.array);

...

return (
  ...
  {array.map(el => (
    <div>{el}</div> // <-- error, can't render object!!
  ))}
);
```

The error is `error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {type, payload})` which is quite obvious the action object dispatched to the Redux store and saved into state.

```
export const array = createSlice({
  name: 'array',
  initialState: {
    value: []
  },
  reducers:{
    append(state, a) {
      state.value.push(a) // <-- `a` is action object `{ type: 'append', payload: 5 }`
    }
  }
});
```

## Solution

I'm sure you meant to save *just* the payload value and not the *entire* action object since the dispatched value `x` is a primitive number type.

```
const dispatch = useDispatch()
let x = 5
dispatch(append(x));
```

Update the reducer function to unpack the payload to save into state.

```
export const array = createSlice({
  name: 'array',
  initialState: {
    value: []
  },
  reducers:{
    append(state, action) {
      state.value.push(action.payload); // 5
    }
  }
});
```